# Crear un vector similar a otro para crear inversa

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Solamente usando For – While – If – Switch Case – Vectores – Printf – Scanf –  Int – Char
>
> Se trabajará con dos vectores, donde el largo del vector debe darlo el usuario por teclado (int largoVector). Una vez que el usuario definió el largo de los vectores se pasa a la carga del primer vector (vector1), el usuario deberá cargar por teclado cada numero entero que forma al vector. Cuando ya tengamos el vector1 cargado con los números del usuario, por ejemplo vector1 ={1,4,5,3,6}, se debe crear el vector vector2, con los números todos invertidos, es decir, por ejemplo,  vector2 = {6,-3,5,4,1}.
>
> B- Mostrar por pantalla a ambos vectores en dos líneas distintas con este formato por consola: El vector 1 esta formado por los números: 1 4 5 -3 6 Y el vector 2 esta formado por los números: 6 -3 5 4 1.

Soy un principiante, y llegué a hacerlo hasta acá:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int largovector=0;
    int vector1[largovector];
    int vector2[largovector];

    printf("Ingrese el largo del vector\n"); //Definimos el largo del vector
    scanf("%d",&largovector);

    for(j=0; j<largovector; j++) //Definimos los numeros del vector
    {
        printf ("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada %d del vector: \n",j);
        scanf ("%d",&vector1[j]);
    }


    printf("El vector 1 esta formado por los numeros: ");//Imprimimos el vector
    for(j=0; j<largovector; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",vector1[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("El vector 2 esta formado por los numeros: ");
    for (i=largovector-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ",&vector2[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Mi problema es que no sé cómo crear un `Vector2[]` que tenga mismas coordenadas que el de `Vector1` para crear la inversa. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Jefren, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general (y así ganar tu primera medalla) y lee [ask] para sugerencias a la hora de escribir/editar una pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que deberías replantear lo de `largovector`, en C, los arrays de tamaño variable no deben inicializarse con cero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso a lo que te entiendo es que quieres obtener un vector y seguido generar otro con el contenido del primero a la inversa. En este caso no te funciona ya que no estás asignando los valores respectivos del primer vector al segundo. Aquí te dejo la solución y espero que te ayude.

```
int main() { int i=0; int j=0; int largovector=0;  

printf("Ingrese el largo del vector\n"); //Definimos el largo del vector
scanf("%d",&largovector);

int vector1[largovector];int vector2[largovector];

for(j=0; j<largovector; j++) //Definimos los numeros del vector
{
printf ("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada %d del vector: \n",j);
scanf ("%d",&vector1[j]);
}
//Asignar los valores del vector1 al  vector2
 for(int contador=0,i=largovector-1;i>=0;i--,contador++){
 vector2[contador]=vector1[i];
 }

printf("El vector 1 esta formado por los numeros: ");//Imprimimos el vector
for(j=0; j<largovector; j++)
{
printf("%d ",vector1[j]);
}
printf("\n");

printf("El vector 2 esta formado por los numeros: ");
for (i=0; i<largovector; i++)
{
printf("%d ",vector2[i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Yordan, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y cómo funciona en general (y así ganar tu primera medalla). Un saludo.